# How to use AVERAGEIF in Google Sheets, only addressing columns with a specific text

Tags: google-sheets, substring, average, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to use `AVERAGEIF` to calculate an **average of only some of the columns** in another table.
The columns to be included in the average are **marked by some text** in a specific cell (e.g. the first or last row of that column).

Some columns are to be included in several averages, so the text in the top\bottom row would include several words (effectively meaning I'll need some sort of substring check such as `FIND`).

I've tried using `AVERAGEIF()` in conjuction with `FIND()` but couldn't get this to work.

Any ideas?

[Here is an example of how the data sheet looks like, and how I would expect it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VM3L.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,A2:A9)),B2:B9,"")))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

For table mentioned in comment you must change ranges:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E2,$A$1:$C$1)),$A$2:$C$4,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @basic, I've tried manipulating your formula but it refuses to work with my format. Would you please have a look at the example I've added and see if you can work this out as well?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VM3L.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query

```
=AVERAGE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($A$1:$D),"where Col1 contains '"&D1&"'"))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`AVERAGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)